# mmap does not work as expected (return random 0xdeadbeef)

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded

I am writing c++ on linux7arm and the physical address is referring to a memory block (that can be accessed/changed by other peripherals) when I map a page of physical address space to the local address space and try to read it, it works fine and show the expected data BUT not all the time. if I write a script to run my compiled c program in a loop and just print the data out it prints 0xdeadbeef randomly. can this be related to physical memory or there is a problem with my code!

```
int page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);

if ((mem_file = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC)) < 0) {
    close(mem_file);
    printf("Error : Unable to open /dev/mem\n");
}
local_address = mmap(
                 NULL,
                 page_size,  // length of the mapped mem
                 PROT_READ,
                 MAP_SHARED,
                 mem_file,
                 (uint32_t)page_address   // starting physical address
                        );

volatile char * start_address=(char *)local_address;
printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<page_size;i++) {
    printf("%x",*(start_address+i)); 
{
printf("\n");
munmap . . .
```

Comment: You set `start_address` to be `local_address` before `local_address` has a valid value returned by `mmap`.

Comment: my bad, this was a typo. My actual code is in the right order. (I have fixed the question, thank you)

Comment: Sure. `0xdeadbeef` is obviously not random and is a common marker value that coders use to initialise memory for various reasons. Are you sure that the memory does not indeed contain that value?

Comment: yes I am sure the memory does not contain 0xdeadbeef but I am not sure if the interface has a problem (the interface between the processor and the memory is a fpga design). so for example when I write a data to a location and read the location again and again , 90% of the time I read what I wrote but some time I read 0xdeadbeef . there is no way that the memory holds 0xdeadbeef because if I read it again (sometimes it take a couple of tries) I will get the old value I wrote on that location.

Comment: Assuming the memory was over written with 0xdeadbeef it is really unlikely for the old value to get restored all by itself! the thing is I did not write the RTL for the fpga design and I need to know if my code is right so that I can refer the problem to the RTL designers!

Comment: Just a suggestion, but why don't you use a standard utility such as `dd` to read /dev/mem for you? That will discount any bugs in your own code. But FWIW, your code looks fine to me.

Comment: you are checking to see that mmap passed/failed yes?   I find it is more likely to be successful/pass if you use a larger size, like huge size, power of two (lots of zeros at the end, 0x10000000 type of thing) and a likewise aligned starting address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two possible issues:

1. You need to  check the return value of mmap in case it fails.
2. You are assuming the peripherals sharing the memory with the CPU are data cache coherent with it. It is possible, but not likely. If they aren't you are bound to see stale data.

Having said that, I doubt what you are seeing is related to either issues and suspect a memory value of 0xdeadbeef is the poor RTL designer way to indicate some error in accessing the memory.